# How to make type as dynamic using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a dynamic data like,

```typescript
const data = {games:{type: [], sport: [], category: []}}
```

And I have hardcoded type like `type Valid = "type" & "sport" & "category"`

How can I make `type Valid` dynamic based on the `Object.keys(data.games)` instead of hardcoding ?

I have tried the following,

```typescript
type Valid = typeof Object.keys(data.games).join(' & ');
```

But this gives the error as,

> Unexpected token, expected ";"

Please help me to get dynamic values for the `type Valid`.

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit disable-dependent-dropdown-option-in-reactjs (forked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want expression is

```typescript
type Valid = keyof typeof data.games
```